# How to open multiple images from Google Drive at once

Tags: google-drive, images

I want to be able to select multiple (30+) jpeg/png images from a folder in Google Drive. I then want to open all of those images in a new tab for each one.

This could be achieved by individually double clicking each image (bringing up the preview for that image) then going to "more actions" at the top right of the screen and selecting "open in new window".

However, I want to be able to do this action to multiple photos at once.

Is this possible? And if yes, how can I do it?

Comment: I want to use google drive to host photos for my website, I use php to generate the html but need the links from google drive. Currently the longest part of the process to get an image working is opening each individual image in a separate tab to copy the URL.

Comment: Once the images are open in each tab, I can copy all of them into a separate script which takes care of adding the photo links to a database, etc.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/drive-preview-images-down/heodcnincjibppngjppnfpaphocjblib

Comment: @bobfredderson on your website, do you need each file to be separate from the rest of the photos? Kinda like if people were to download the file?

Answer (score 0):

- go to your Drive
- right-click on Folders/Files/somewhere
- select **More**
- select **+ Connect more apps**

  [image]
- type in **Drive Preview Images Downloader**
- hit **<kbd>Enter</kbd>** key
- and click on **+ CONNECT** button

  [image]
- follow all steps...
- etc.
- once when you done, go to your folder with images
- select them (you can do so with **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>**+**<kbd>A</kbd>** combo)
- right click on them
- select **Open with**
- select **Drive Preview Images Downloader**

  [image]
- new window opens...
- and then just select image and right-click on image preview
- and select **Copy image address**
- if you want so you can open them in new tabs too with that blue **<kbd>New</kbd>** button

  [image]

Comment: This solution still required me to go through each individual photo and select "copy image address", which takes longer than just opening a photo and clicking "open in new window".
If this tool were to have an "open all photos each in a new tab" it would be perfect, but I can't seem to find an option to do that.

Comment: @bobfredderson not sure if you tried it out or not... the way I see it you will save time & resources if you just: **righ-click>copy_address>arrow_down>righ-click>copy_next_address>arrow_down...** if you dont want so save resources only time then: **mousewheel-click_on_New _button>arrow_down>mousewheel-click_on_New _button>arrow_down>mousewheel-click_on_New _button>arrow_down...**

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to put the photos on a website, I recommend using Google Photos instead. This assumes it is okay for the photos to be displayed together, rather than being separate files intended for download.

Go to [photos.google.com](https://photos.google.com/), click on "Upload" on the top right, and click on "Google Drive" to import photos from Google Drive.

You can select the photos you [recently added](https://photos.google.com/search/_tra_) by clicking on the search bar at the top, then "Show more" and then "Recently added". Create a new album out of those photos from the + icon on the top right (once the photos are selected). Then, go to the album and share it with a link (and do not let others add photos with the link).

Use that link on your website. The album will not be on your website (which saves storage space on your website), but it will be easy for people to view the photos/images in the album site, which works well on mobile as well as on a computer. Photos can still be viewed individually by clicking on them, then moving to the next photo to the right or left.